# Creating an Infinite Series with a Specific Property

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hello Mathematicians,

Recently I have been doing some work which has an interesting application to another problem as a consequence. However many searches for this latter problem have not returned a proper name for it, so I would be very grateful if you could help...

Problem: Specify an infinite sequence $a_n(\lambda)$, dependent on both $n$ and $\lambda$ in a non-trivial way, such that

\begin{equation}
\sum_n a_n(\lambda)^2=\rho\left(\sum_n a_n(\lambda)\right)^2,
\end{equation}

where $\lambda$ may be altered to satisfy any finite value of the constant $\rho$.

I can solve this implicitly for $\rho\in\mathbb{R}$ under certain assumptions on the behaviour of $a_n(\lambda)$ and additionally can give methods for approximating $a_n(\lambda)$ to relatively high accuracy. The proof is a bit specialised and so I am mainly interested in more general work by others

Thank you for any help

Comment: What are $\lambda$ and $\rho$ in this question? Parameters? Variables? I find the question hard to understand.

Comment: I don't really see why you need to use the letter $\lambda$ at all.  It looks like you want a sequence of functions $a_n$ that depend only on $\rho$.

Comment: have you tried looking for finite sequences (with only 3, 4 or 5 terms) with $a_n(\lambda)$ given explicitely as, say, polynomial functions?

Comment: @ Yemon: $\rho$ is just a constant and $\lambda$ is the variable. So for example, not that it would work, you might have $a_n(\lambda)\equiv 1/(n+\lambda)^3$

@ S. Carnahan: $\lambda$ is just to indicate that $a_n$ is not dependent solely on $n$. Otherwise the problem could be solved by finding the solution for $\rho=1$ and then just letting $a_n\rightarrow \sqrt{\rho} a_n$

@ Olivier: Not yet. In a sense, at least with my current approach, it's easier to search for infinite sequences

Comment: I'm pretty sure putting $a_0(x)=\sin(x),~a_1(x)=\sin(\sqrt{2}x)$ will do the job.

Comment: I have altered the wording a little so to be clearer


Comment: nevermind, it will only give you solutions for big values of $\rho$ but probably not for $\rho<<1$

Comment: From the original question: "non-trivially dependent" - sorry, this is just too vague and meaningless. Why don't you give some "trivially dependent" examples first and say why you don't accept them.

Better yet, say why you want such a series; what will you do with it?

By the way, just for fun, $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right)^2 dx$.

Comment: ...of course those integrals don't have any particular significance, it's just for fun. But, e.g. why not take $a_n(\lambda) = f(\lambda)b_n$ for any $f$ you like, and any $b_n$ for which $\sum b_n$, $\sum b_n^2$ both converge; and you can change $b_n$ in various ways (just changing the first term is probably enough) to get various $\rho$. If this is not what you want, why not? 

Comment: @ Zen: Sorry I should have been more specific. I meant that $a_n(\lambda)$ must depend on $\lambda$ in a non-trivial way. For example $a_n(\lambda)\equiv 1/(n+\lambda)^3$ would be fine whereas $a_n(\lambda) \equiv 1/(n+1)^3$ would not be. I'm interested in the series just out of mathematical curiosity

Comment: OK, so is $a_n(\lambda) = f(\lambda)b_n$ allowed, or not? If not, why not? Put more conditions on this $\lambda$ dependence!

To be honest, this question looks like you're just making up random equations for its own sake; this can be great fun, but I don't see its relevance to mathematical research (unless you have a specific problem which needs this kind of construction, and even then it seems a bit too localised to me).

Comment: @ Zen: Sorry I didn't see your second reply for some reason. No, I would not allow $a_n(\lambda)=f(\lambda)b_n$ as the problem is then reduced to solving $f(\lambda)=1/\rho$. I suppose the actual problem would be to find a series $a_n(\lambda)$ satisfying a more general equation than the one given, possibly with sums of $\sum a_n(\lambda)^3$ etc

Comment: I don't think this is a real question, since there is a large number of valid answers, which the OP does not like for some internal reason. Voting to close.

Comment: The conditions on $a_n(\lambda)$ are in their present form far too vague - what does "non-trivial dependence" mean? Are we allowing functions of the form $a_n(\lambda)$ = (integer part of $\lambda^n$)/(sum of factors of $n$)? This is a perfectly valid function depending on $n$ and $\lambda$ in some non-trivial way

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n=a_n(\lambda)=\lambda^n$ then $\sum a_n^2=\frac{1}{1-\lambda^2}$ while $(\sum a_n)^2=\frac{1}{(1-\lambda)^2}$ So $\lambda=\frac{1-\rho}{1+\rho}$ makes $
\sum_n a_n(\lambda)^2=\rho\left(\sum_n a_n(\lambda)\right)^2$ for any $\rho \gt 0.$

Comment: FWIW, I think the OP wants $\rho$ to be specified and the identity to hold for all $\lambda$ (though given how ill-defined the original question is, I am largely guessing.